# How to replace JS array property values using another JS array

Tags: javascript

I want to replace JS array property values using another JS array. I have explained as below.

```
const arr1 = [
{
  code: "XXY",
  dis: "cont1",
  note: "Note for cont1"
}, 
{
  code: "AAW",
  dis: "cont2",
  note: "Note for cont2"
}, 
{
  code: "TTR",
  dis: "cont5",
  note: "Note for cont5"
}, 
{
  code: "MMN",
  dis: "cont10",
  note: "Note for cont10"
}]
```

```
const new_array = [
  {
    "code": "AAW",
    "dis": "cont2 new",
    "note": "Note for cont2"
  },
  {
    "code": "TTR",
    "dis": "cont5",
    "note": "New Note for cont5"
  }]
```

Expected output:

```
[
 {
  code: "XXY",
  dis: "cont1",
  note: "Note for cont1"
 }, 
 {
  code: "AAW",
  dis: "cont2 new",
  note: "Note for cont2"
 }, 
 {
  code: "TTR",
  dis: "cont5",
  note: "New Note for cont5"
 }, 
 {
  code: "MMN",
  dis: "cont10",
  note: "Note for cont10"
 }
]
```

We need to check all `arr1` element where equal `new_arr.code` to `arr1.code` and compare `dis` and `note` properties. If `arr1.dis` not equals `new_arr.dis` then `arr1.dis` value should be replaced by `new_arr.dis`. This is same to `note` property also.

Tried code:

```
arr1.forEach(function(item1) {
        var item2 = arr1.find(function (item2) {
            return arr1.code === new_array.code;
        });
    })

console.log(arr1);
```

Current output:

```
[
  {
    "code": "XXY",
    "dis": "cont1",
    "note": "Note for cont1"
  },
  {
    "code": "AAW",
    "dis": "cont2",
    "note": "Note for cont2"
  },
  {
    "code": "TTR",
    "dis": "cont5",
    "note": "Note for cont5"
  },
  {
    "code": "MMN",
    "dis": "cont10",
    "note": "Note for cont10"
  }
]
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: "does not work" is not enough for us to diagnose the problem. What output are you getting? Are there any errors?

Comment: If you want to check _every_ element of the first array, against _every_ element of the second - then of course this won’t work by just looping over one of them.

Comment: array find() is what you need to use

Comment: "We need to check all arr1 element where equal new_arr.code to arr1.code and compare dis and note properties." - Exactly... so do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new_array.forEach(o1 => { // for every replacement object
  // find the corresponding object in the original array
  const found = arr1.find(o2 => o2.code === o1.code); 
  // if there is a corresponding object
  if (found) {
    // copy its properties over
    found.dis = o1.dis;
    found.note = o1.note;
  }
})
```

Note this has a poor `O(n^2)` time complexity, consider using a set for faster lookups as recommended by other answers if you have a large dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Given a method which can merge an item from the original, with an array of possible updates:

```
const mergeItem = (item, arr, finder) =>{
  var other = arr.find(x => finder(item,x));
  if(other != null){
    Object.entries(other).forEach(([key,value]) => item[key] = value);
  }
  return item;
}
```

The code to merge the 2 arrays is fairly straightforward

```
var result = arr1.map(item => mergeItem(item,new_array, (x,y) => x.code == y.code));
```

Live example:

```js
const arr1 = [{"code":"XXY","dis":"cont1","note":"Note for cont1"},{"code":"AAW","dis":"cont2","note":"Note for cont2"},{"code":"TTR","dis":"cont5","note":"Note for cont5"},{"code":"MMN","dis":"cont10","note":"Note for cont10"}];
const new_array = [{"code":"AAW","dis":"cont2 new","note":"Note for cont2"},{"code":"TTR","dis":"cont5","note":"New Note for cont5"}];
  
  
const mergeItem = (item, arr, finder) =>{
  var other = arr.find(x => finder(item,x));
  if(other != null){
    Object.entries(other).forEach(([key,value]) => item[key] = value);
  }
  return item;
}

var result = arr1.map(item => mergeItem(item,new_array, (x,y) => x.code == y.code));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const mappedArray = arr1.map((x) => {
  const filteredValue = new_array.filter((y) => y.code === x.code);
  return filteredValue.length > 0 ? filteredValue[0] : x;
});
```

Comment: I think it would improve your answer if you added some explanation for @aer-der about what you've changed in their code to answer their question.

Answer (score 3):

Create an object with second array where code is a key to find element in O(1) time So, complexity reduce to O(n) time.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    code: "XXY",
    dis: "cont1",
    note: "Note for cont1"
  },
  {
    code: "AAW",
    dis: "cont2",
    note: "Note for cont2"
  },
  {
    code: "TTR",
    dis: "cont5",
    note: "Note for cont5"
  },
  {
    code: "MMN",
    dis: "cont10",
    note: "Note for cont10"
  }
]

const new_array = [{
    "code": "AAW",
    "dis": "cont2 new",
    "note": "Note for cont2"
  },
  {
    "code": "TTR",
    "dis": "cont5",
    "note": "New Note for cont5"
  }
]

const t = new_array.reduce((res, item) => {
  res[item.code] = item
  return res;
}, {})

arr1.forEach(item => {
  const found = t[item.code]
  if (found) {
    item.dis = found.dis
    item.note = found.note
  }
})
console.log(arr1)
```